# Matlab Simulation using Webots!

Tags: control, mobile-robot, first-robotics, webots

[image]

I am trying to run this youbot ( sample world) from webots, where the controller is implemented in MATLAB, on running the code it pops out the following error seen in the picture attached. I have also however installed the Support for MinGW-w64 C/C++ Compiler, though it still shows the same error. Could someone help a bit? The error is as follows:

````
Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\Webots\lib\matlab 
> In path (line 109)
  In addpath (line 86)
  In launcher (line 23) 
The MATLAB "MinGW-w64 C/C++ Compiler" addon is not installed, please install it from: https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52848-matlab-support-for-mingw-w64-c-c-compiler
Waiting up to 5 seconds for C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\webots_matlab_lock to be deleted by another MATLAB instance.
Deleting C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\webots_matlab_lock...
Creating: C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Temp\protofile_matlab_2018b_webots_R2020a_revision_1.m
Load Library failed.
Error using loadlibrary
Could not find file allincludes.h.

Error in loadlibrary

Error in launcher (line 74)
      loadlibrary( ...
```
````

Comment: please include the actual error text, not a picture of text

Comment: I added the error! I hope it is fine now?

Comment: I voted to close this question because there are no details of what OP has done to try to solve the problem, like installing the Webots library or installing a MEX compiler.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two serious problems clearly stated in your error message:

> Warning: Name is nonexistent or not a directory: C:\Program Files\Webots\lib\matlab

And

> The MATLAB "MinGW-w64 C/C++ Compiler" addon is not installed, please install it

Have you fixed these problems? It looks like you don't have the Webots library installed and you also don't have a compiler installed. Nothing is going to work and we can't provide any other assistance until you get these resolved (and resolving them may fix everything).